# Preloading js into iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am building an `iFrame` to be used by third parties. Now, for the `iFrame`, I need some vendor files like `jQuery, jQuery-UI, jQuery-validate, font-awesome`. This has elongated the loading process. What are the solutions for faster loading??

Some solutions that I have in mind are:

1) Most probably the client will have some of them already loaded. Some how if I could use them, that could shorten the loading time. But I tried doing that with no success.

2) The customer is likely to browse through the client site before using my `iFrame`. If I could use that time to download the files and then inject them into the `iFrame`, it could too shorten the time lag.

**My Approach:**

I added the `jQuery` file to the `head` of the `iFrame` as shown below:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js';
$('#pg-iframe').contents().find("head").append(s);
```

However when the server renders the page of `iFrame`, the head tag is replaced by the head tag of the rendered page. As a result, I need to have the `script` tags in the html page too thereby ending with multiple downloads.

Am I thinking the right way or have messed it up. It could be great to have some feedback.

Comment: "multiple downloads"? The scripts will be cached by the browser after the first download.

Comment: I had assumed the same, but that's not happening. Like when I inject the `jQuery` into the iFrame, it takes around `500ms` to get the file and again when the iFrame is rendered by the server, it takes another `1-2 seconds` to fetch the file.